# My Schengen visa and UK visa are valid until November, am I ok to travel in September/October?

Tags: uk, schengen, visas

I am from China and my Schengen visa is valid until 2nd of November this year. My UK dependent visa will expire at the same time as well.

I am just wondering if I am allowed to travel 3 months before my UK visa expired?

I have seen lots of information online about Schengen visa application requirements and they all saying the applicant needs to have a valid UK visa for at least 3 months in order to apply for Schengen visa.  Is it the same for people who have already have a valid Schengen visa? I am not sure if that apply on my case too. Really hope I can get an answer to confirm this so that I can go ahead and book my journey.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Are you planning to go back before your visa expires?

Answer (score 4):

Your visa says it expires on the 2 November, that means before that time, you can travel around Europe, that's what the expiry date is there for - to tell you when you are allowed to travel until.

Answer (score -1):

You have UK residency visa and you want to apply for Schengen visa from the UK.
For example Tourist visa to Germany require that your UK residency permit is valid 90 days after you leave Schengen.

> UK residence permit (original and copy): valid for at least 90 days
>   beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen area. [Ref](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html)

Comment: This seems to answer a completely different question than the quite old one it is posted as an answer to. (The OP of this question _already had_ a Schengen visa; that's the first sentence of the question).

Comment: yes, it will expire too and he wants to apply for a new one from the UK. this is what i understand.

Comment: But the question is not about applying for a new visa.

Comment: " they all saying the applicant needs to have a valid UK visa for at least 3 months in order to apply for Schengen visa."

Comment: @AhmedHashim: Yes -- the OP knew the rule that you cannot _apply_ for a visa while living on a soon-to-expire residence permit, and his question was whether that rule means, by extension, that you cannot _use_ an existing visa while living on a soon-to-expire residence permit. The answer to that is, "no, it doesn't".